# Edit multiple Lights

Tags: light, scene, lighting

Is it possible to edit multiple lights?

For example I have 8 lights. 4 of them need to be red and the others green. Now when I change settings of one of the lamp's color or strength value, the others of the same group should also change and copy the values I have set for the one lamp.

Greetings and Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Select the lamps you want to share the same data, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and choose object data. The corresponding lamps will now always copy each others settings.
[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thats what i was looking for. Thank you :)

Comment: Good, could you mark my answer as 'answered'?

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you don't want to give me reputation, I might as well take some of yours away. Please hit the little green check symbol next to my answer. Then we both get some reputation and others might find this thread useful.

Comment: @Hendriks3D while I sure understand the frustration of not getting an answer accepted (where the OP comments saying how you helped them), down voting the question out of spite is just not right.

Comment: Downvoting on stackexchange doesn't mean you don't like the question, but it means you disagree with it.

Comment: @Hendriks3D please read: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2396/down-voting-a-question-because-the-op-didnt-accept-your-answer

Comment: Sorry. I never noticed that checker symbol.

Comment: cegaton and david. Why do you guys even care? XD

Comment: @Hendriks3D Well, David is a mod, so... that's kind of his job.